# Getting started with OAuth

Tags: oauth

I wanted to build a simple WP7 app to learn how to use Silverlight, so I thought I'd create a very simple yammer app.  As a starter it would have two screens - Login (Username & Password) and Feed.

Yammer user OAuth for its authentication but I just dont get it!  i appreciate you need to request a token to use the REST interfaces, but I dont want my users (even if its just me) to need anything other than their login credentials, as they would use on the website.  In my head the token can be used in a similar manner as a forms auth token in asp.net

Am I missing something?  But I cant see anything in the yammer documentation about logging in.

Answer (score 1):

The process for OAuth is as follows

1. You do a token request to Yammer. If needed they will ask for yammer credentials and send a token back to a URL of your application
2. You must use that token to sign all your petitions.

You can't stop Yammer asking for credentials because that's the idea of OAuth. Yammer does not trust you and it's impossible for you to keep any user Yammer's credentials. That way they can't be stolen from your site. The more you can store is a temporal token.

Comment: Cheers, I understand the token bit (sort of) but the bit I don't get is the auth part in via a non-web app, but I'll check out the huniversw app first

Answer (score 0):

There is a very good guide to using OAuth on [hueniverse](http://hueniverse.com/2007/10/beginners-guide-to-oauth-part-i-overview/), which features an example workflow. It's not completely up to date with the latest version of the spec, although this probably doesn't matter too much for your purposes.